# How to average rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table that topic title, and another that contain replies (per topic)

How do I get the average replies per topic (by total)?

```
tkts_topics

id  open_by     status
12  4             3
2   2             3


tkts_replies

id  tkt_id  open_by     name    text
2    2       2          asaf    some text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to divide counts from the two tables:

```
select ( (select count(*) from tkts_replies) /
         (select count(*) from tkts_topics)
       ) as avg_replies_per_topic
```

Comment: wait, i want to calculate the average  replies of topics with status = 3, do i need to write `select count(*) from tkts_replies WHERE STATUS = 3` ?

Comment: @Roi . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a new *question*, not *comment*.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and group by topic id to get the number of replies for each topic.
Then get the average of all these numbers:

```
select avg(g.counter) averagereplies from (
  select count(r.id) counter
  from tkts_topics t left join tkts_replies r
  on r.tkt_id = t.id 
  where t.status = 3
  group by t.id 
) g
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cSfzfMfYRHj4WiaV3UNgHM/0).